# Windows 7 how to change the LDAP user's password from command line

Tags: command-line, windows-7, ldap, passwords, remote-desktop

I am doing a remote desktop connection to a windows 7 box and I wanted to change its LDAP user password due to the corporate policies. I am not able to send Ctrl+Atl+Del to the remote desktop and wanted to know an alternative way to achieve this, either via command line or using VBscript.

Please help....

Comment: Can you use Ctrl+Alt+End?

Comment: What do you mean by "LDAP user"?  Do you just mean a user in the Active Directory, or are you using some sort of third-party authentication system?

Comment: Yeah.. Active Directory user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok.. I got the solution. I need to click the security menu after I click the start button on the remote desktop. That will allow me to change the password.

We can now close this question.